# Can only use WSJTX in sudo

Tags: ft8, linux, wsjt-x

I am trying to use WSJT-X to make FT8 Contacts on Pop! OS (Ubuntu-based) and with an IC-7300. I entered all the correct settings into WSJT-X, but it could not connect to my transceiver, and WSJT-X gave an Access Denied error. I tried running WSJT-X with sudo, and it worked perfectly. I also tried to use Flrig and Fldigi, and they only worked with sudo as well. How can I get it to work without sudo?

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that your user is not in the dialout group. You can fix this with:

```
sudo adduser your_user_name dialout
```

Then log out and back in.

Answer (score 1):

Probably, some or all files are owned by root.

Chown the files and change the ownership to yourself, for example.